# Syntax Error: Operator expected in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error every time I try to compile this buffer. I've gone through the ordinary steps of removing all spaces, but still I keep getting the same error every time.

```
solve_puzzle(Swimmers):-
    Swimmers=[_Girl1,_Girl2,_Girl3],
    [girl(_,_,_,first),girl(_,_,_,second),girl(_,_,_,third)]=Swimmers,
    is_faster(girl(claudia,_,_,_),(_,_,cheltenham_girls,_),Swimmers),
    is_faster(girl(mary,_,_,_),girl(_,table_tennis,_,_),Swimmers),
    member(girl(_,weightlifting,_,first),Swimmers),
    member(girl(mary,_,sydney_girls_high_school,_),Swimmers),
    member(girl(claudia,ballroom_dancing,_,_),Swimmers),
    member(girl(_,_,hornsby_girls_high_school,_),Swimmers).

is_faster(F,S,[F|[S|_]]).
is_faster(F,S,[F,S,[_|Rest]]):- is_faster[F,S,Rest).
```

Whats doing this? I seem to run into this every time I attempt prolog.

Comment: SWI even tells you the exact line of the error. Write:
`is_faster(F, S, [F,S,_|Rest]) :-  is_faster(F, S, Rest).` to at least fix the syntax error (semantic problems may still be present). Removing all spaces is certainly *not* required or recommended. Also, check out more convenient list syntax: You can write the penultimate clause equivalently as `is_faster(F, S, [F,S,_]).` (again, just considering syntax, and leaving the semantics unchanged).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has nothing that the [comment by @mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580525/syntax-error-operator-expected-in-swi-prolog#comment53015328_32580525) does not, but still:

I saved the code as you show it to a file named `foo.pl`, then, when I try to load (consult) the file, I get:

```
?- [foo].
ERROR: foo.pl:12:41: Syntax error: Operator expected
true.
```

So, `foo.pl:12:41` is filename: `foo.pl`, line number: `12`, column: `41`.

This is the last line, the column right before you open a bracket `[` which you close with a parenthesis `)`.

Normally, you would show in your question the exact error message that you get when you try to compile a program (as a general rule on Stack Overflow, not only for Prolog). Please see ["how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and what is a ["minimal, complete, and verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

PS. There is nothing ordinary in removing spaces as far as I am aware. Is this a debugging technique?

Comment: @David I highly recommend you read through the two links I included in my answer ("how to ask", "MCVE"). Just following the advice they give will make you a better programmer now and in the future.